# Work with variables in two conditions

Tags: php, variables, conditional-statements

I have a problem with the work with variables from one condition in the second condition. I have something like that:

```
<form name="exampleForm" method="post">
...
<input type="submit" name="firstSubmit" value="Send">
<input type="submit" name="secondSubmit" value="Show">
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['firstSubmit'])) {

 function a() {
  $a = 5;
  $b = 6;
  $c = $a + $b;
  echo "The result is $c";
  return $c;
 }

 $functionOutput = a();
}

if(isset($_POST['secondSubmit'])) {

 echo $functionOutput;
}
?>
```

When I need to work with variable `$functionOutput` from first condition I always get an error message (undefined variable). How I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$functionOutput = "";

if(isset($_POST['firstSubmit'])) {

 function a() {
  $a = 5;
  $b = 6;
  $c = $a + $b;
  echo "The result is $c";
  return $c;
 }

 $functionOutput = a();
}

if(isset($_POST['secondSubmit'])) {

 echo $functionOutput;
}
?>
```

Should fix it. It's happening because you're declaring $functionOutput inside your first IF statement.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do exactly, but when you press your second button, the variable `$functionOutput` is not defined as the first condition is `false` so that whole section is skipped.

Note that variables are lost as soon as the script ends. You could look into [sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php) and use session variables to solve that, but it depends a bit on what you want to do exactly.

To use sessions, you would have to move your whole php block to before where you start outputting html and do something like:

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['firstSubmit'])) {

 function a() {
  $a = 5;
  $b = 6;
  $c = $a + $b;
  return $c;
 }

 $_SESSION['output'] = a();
}


// start html output
?>
<doctype .....
<html ....

// and where you want to echo
if(isset($_POST['firstSubmit'])) {
  echo "The result is {$_SESSION['output']}";
}

if(isset($_POST['secondSubmit'])) {

 echo $_SESSION['output'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have one more question. Is safe use sessions ?

Comment: @Mato Sure, all information is stored server-side. There is a bit more to it, you can add session and form variables to avoid session hijacking but you'd have to look that up for more details.

Answer (score 1):

As `$functionOutput` is not initialized when you are calling `if(isset($_POST['secondSubmit']))`

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['firstSubmit'])) {

 function a() {
  $a = 5;
  $b = 6;
  $c = $a + $b;
  echo "The result is $c";
  return $c;
 }

 $functionOutput = a();
}
$functionOutput='12';//intialize
if(isset($_POST['secondSubmit'])) {

 echo $functionOutput;
}
?> 

         **OR**

<?php
if(isset($_POST['firstSubmit'])) {

 function a() {
  $a = 5;
  $b = 6;
  $c = $a + $b;
  echo "The result is $c";
  return $c;
 }

 $functionOutput = a();
}

if(isset($_POST['secondSubmit'])) {
 function a() {
  $a = 5;
  $b = 6;
  $c = $a - $b;
  echo "The result is $c";
  return $c;
 }

 $functionOutput = a();
 echo $functionOutput;
}
?>
```